# Can we store double value in long without type casting?

Tags: java, variables, casting

I have a Double value, can I store in a long variable without any typecasting > Is this possible?

Comment: did you give it a try ?

Answer (score 2):

You can, try this:

```
    double d = 123.0;
    long l = Double.doubleToLongBits(d);
    d = Double.longBitsToDouble(l);
    System.out.println(d);
```

this will store binary representation of double in long.

To store actual value (truncation possible):

```
long l = Double.valueOf(123.0).longValue();
```

Answer (score -1):

No without explicit typecasting you can't assign value to long variable.
If you are trying without typecasting you will find "loss of precision error".

Comment: seen `Double.valueOf(double).longValueOf()` ??

Comment: @ Nishanth As you mentioned I tried but I get error while executing your mentioned function.


class Test{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  long l = Double.valueOf(56.78).longValueOf();
  System.out.println(l);
 }

}


Error - 
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Java Sandeep$ javac Test.java
Test.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
  long l = Double.valueOf(56.78).longValueOf();
                                ^
  symbol:   method longValueOf()
  location: class Double

Comment: Use appropriate quotation while answering/commenting in SO

Comment: sorry!, its `Double.valueOf(double).longValue()` .